# how do square brackets [ ] work in this swift ui example? does it pass its returned value to ‘i’?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How do square brackets `[ ]` work here?? Does it pass its returned value to ‘i’?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var conductor = DrumsConductor()
    @State var downPads: [Int] = []

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10){
            ForEach(0..<2, id:     \.self) { row in
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..<4, id: \.self) { column in
                        ZStack {

                            /// here!
                            Text(self.conductor.drumSamples.map({ (i: DrumSample) -> String in i.name })[getPadId(row: row, column: column)])
                                .foregroundColor(Color(.white)).fontWeight(.bold)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
        private func getPadId(row: Int, column: Int) -> Int {
        return (row * 4) + column
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews:     PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started with:

```
self.conductor.drumSamples.map({ (i: DrumSample) -> String in i.name })[getPadId(row: row, column: column)]
```

Making it easier to read (won't compile in `@ViewBuilder`):

```
let index = getPadId(row: row, column: column)

self.conductor.drumSamples.map({ (i: DrumSample) -> String in
    i.name
})[index]
```

The `map` returns an array, and the square brackets (`[]`) are just used to subscript to get the element at that index in that array.

From your question, I can see that `getPadId(row:column:)` is creating an ID based on the row and column. The top-left `Text` will be ID `0`, increasing from left-to-right and then down. This ensures that every view has a unique ID, meaning that the `Text` will display each `self.conductor.drumSamples`'s `name` property.

However, it's wasteful to create the whole array and then get a specific index after. Instead, try this before:

```
Text(self.conductor.drumSamples[getPadId(row: row, column: column)].name)
```

Comment: Idk what the type of `drumSamples`, there’s a huge improvement that can be made here: do the subscript if first, then just call `.name` on the result. This avoids the wasteful computation of all the names (where only one would be used)

Comment: @Alexander Yep that's definitely the way, I'll improve the answer now - thanks!

Comment: i’m getting this error “Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(DrumSample)”

Comment: @systar Then I'm assuming `self.conductor.drumSamples` is of type `[String]` rather than `[DrumSample]`, then. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, self.conductor.drumSamples is of type [DrumSample]